# Finding the Difference between Rows and Formatting Into New DF

Tags: python, csv

This is my first time working with dataframes in Python. Here is the question:

"Calculate the difference in the number of Occupied Housing Units from year to year and print it. The difference must be calculated for the consecutive years such as 2008-2009, 2009-2010 etc. Finally, print the values in the ascending order."

Below is my code. It does work but i know there has to be a more efficient way to accomplish this aside from the brute force, manual data entry method that I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unt-iialab/INFO5731_Spring2020/master/Assignments/Assignment1_denton_housing.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

A = data.loc[(data["title_field"]=="Occupied Housing Units") , ["title_field", 'value']]


data_2 = [['2008-2009', 35916-36711],['2009-2010', 41007-35916],['2010-2011', 40704-41007],['2011-2012', 42108-40704],['2012-2013', 43673-42108],['2013-2014', 46295-43673]]  
B = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns = ['Years', 'Difference'])
sort_by_diff = B.sort_values('Difference') 

print(sort_by_diff)
```

Comment: Here's a hint: a row can be subtracted from another row using `.shift()`.

Comment: You're welcome. To clarify: use `.shift()` to get another row of your DataFrame to perform the subtraction with.